# Find an expression for nth term and obtain 17th term

Tags: sequences-and-series

A teacher gave this but it got me confused. we were asked to find an expression for the nth term and hence obtain the 17th term. Below is the full question.

"The 4th and 9th term of an AP is 18 and 43 respectively. Find an expression for the nth term and hence obtain the 17th term"

Could anyone help me solve this and maybe with a little explanation.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: the common difference is $43-18$ divided by $9-4$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Just a small system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}a_4=a_1+3d=18\\{}\\
a_9=a_1+8d=43\end{cases}\;\;\implies5d=43-18\implies d=5\;,\;\;\text{and etc.}$$

Answer (score 0):

Say the common difference is $d$. Then there are five $d$'s between the fourth and the ninth terms. So $43-18=5d$. Now you have $d=5$. You can now find the first term which is $18-(5\times 3)=3$. So the $n^{th}$ term is $3+(n-1)d$ because from the first to the $n^{th}$ term you need to go through $(n-1)$ number of $d$'s.